# How to prevent netbeans from scrolling to bottom of the file after ctrl + a

Tags: netbeans

When I select all text in the editor (ctrl + a), the code scrolls down to the bottom.
Is there a way to prevent it from doing so? Or at least to return quickly to where I've been?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a shortcut to return to the last edit (Tools - Options - Keymap - Last edit), by default it is Ctrl+Q.

Haven't found anything else.