# Disable scroll to the bottom on Select All in NetBeans editor

Tags: netbeans

Of course it's possible to achieve through editing source code of NetBeans and compiling it, but it feels like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152732/7127490
By protasovams

> There is a shortcut to return to the last edit (Tools - Options - Keymap - Last edit), by default it is Ctrl+Q.
>   Haven't found anything else.

Hope this helps